# How to make a panel with light white border by script (I want to to add my label and button to a panel ) in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to make a panel by script in unity and add my label and button to the panel
My existing Gui modal popup code is as shown below

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic; 
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel; 
    // example:
    // HFTDialog.MessageBox("error", "Sorry but you're S.O.L", () => { Application.Quit() });

    public class HFTDialog : MonoBehaviour {
        Rect m_windowRect;
        Action m_action;
        string m_title;
        string m_msg;
        string[] m_myNewsTitleColl;
        string[] m_myColl;
        GUIStyle labelStyle, labelStyleShadow, buttonStyle, sliderStyle, sliderThumbStyle;
        // The position on of the scrolling viewport
        public Vector2 scrollPosition = Vector2.zero;
        private GUIStyle guiStyle; //create a new variable

        static public void MessageBox(string[] myNewsTitleColl, string[] myColl,string title, string msg, Action action)
        {
            GameObject go = new GameObject("HFTDialog");
            HFTDialog dlg = go.AddComponent<HFTDialog>();
            dlg.Init(myNewsTitleColl,myColl,title, msg, action);
        }

        static public void CloseMessageBox(GameObject go)
        {
           Destroy(go.gameObject);
        }

        void Init( string[] myNewsTitleColl,string[] myColl,string title, string msg, Action action)
        {
            m_title = title;
            m_msg = msg;
            m_action = action;
            m_myColl=myColl;
            m_myNewsTitleColl=myNewsTitleColl;
        }

        void OnGUI()
        {
            const int maxWidth  = 640;
            const int maxHeight = 480;//480;
            int width           = Mathf.Min(maxWidth, Screen.width - 20);
            int height          = Mathf.Min(maxHeight, Screen.height - 20);
            m_windowRect        = new Rect((Screen.width - width) / 2,(Screen.height - height) / 2,width,height);
            GUI.color           = Color.white;
            GUI.backgroundColor = Color.yellow;
            m_windowRect        = GUI.Window(0, m_windowRect, WindowFunc, m_title);

        }

        void WindowFunc(int windowID)
        {
            const int border  = 10;
            const int width   = 50;
            const int height  = 25;
            const int spacing = 10;

            Rect ls = new Rect(
                border,
                border + spacing,
                m_windowRect.width - border * 2,
                m_windowRect.height - border * 2 - height - spacing);
            //Start Scrollview test
            scrollPosition    = GUI.BeginScrollView(ls, scrollPosition, new Rect(0, 0, 600, 4800));//Increase the height if more scrolling is needed

            guiStyle = new GUIStyle();
            guiStyle.fontStyle = FontStyle.Bold;
            guiStyle.normal.textColor = Color.white;


            int myNewsTitlePositionY=border + spacing;//Initial position 
            if(m_myNewsTitleColl.Length==0){
               Rect l = new Rect(border, myNewsTitlePositionY,m_windowRect.width - border * 2,m_windowRect.height - border * 2 - height - spacing);
               GUI.Label(l, "Currently No News Available ,Please try later..",guiStyle);//This is the news title label
            }
           else{
        for(var i = 0; i < m_myNewsTitleColl.Length; i++)
        {
               var NewsTitle = m_myNewsTitleColl[i];
               Rect l = new Rect(border, myNewsTitlePositionY,m_windowRect.width - border * 2,m_windowRect.height - border * 2 - height - spacing);
               GUI.Label(l, NewsTitle,guiStyle);//This is the news title label
               myNewsTitlePositionY=myNewsTitlePositionY+33;//next y position of the news title label
            }
           }

        int myY=-15;
        for(var i = 0; i < m_myColl.Length; i++)
        {
             var newsItemLink = m_myColl[i];
             // work with news link item here to make a button
             myY=myY+33; //Y position  of button
                 //Rect btn = new Rect(550,myY,  width+25,  height);    
             Rect   btn = new Rect(510,myY,  width+25,  height);  //when scroll enable -  
             if (GUI.Button(btn, "Open Link"))
                {               
                 Application.OpenURL(newsItemLink );//open browser pointing the url
                }
             Debug.Log ("from string array value is :"+newsItemLink );
        }
        //End Scrollview
        GUI.EndScrollView();

      //Close button 
           Rect b = new Rect(
                m_windowRect.width - width - border,
                m_windowRect.height - height - border,
                width,
                height);
            if (GUI.Button(b, "close"))
            {
                Destroy(this.gameObject);
              //  m_action();
            }


        }
    }
```

Panel must be as shown in the picture (my blue color drawing is assumed as a panel - in which the label and button must be held together):
Also how can I make my modal popup background more darker ,is there a way to make it opaque or can I set opaque value for this Modal GUI?

[image: My modal popup]